# SQL Query Group by Date Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I've a database table where I store data 3 to 9 times in a minute. I store data with **ID** ,  **XYZ** value and **CreateDateTime** Value

Now, I want to write a script where the return value shows maximum value of XYZ in every Minute.

Please help me to write this script.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, createdatetime), 0)
                                order by xyz desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note:  This returns the row in each minute with the maximum value.